Scroll to behaviour not working good in construct 3
I just started making game in Construct 3. I used 'Scroll To' behaviour on a sprite to move the camera as the sprite moves. but the sprite often comes out of camera and i am confused what mistake am i making.
Screenshot of the studio
This is link of my construct3 file
please point out the mistake and suggest me a soultion fot this.
I tried to change the viewport size, sprite size, obstacle size but nothing worke.
at last i created a seperate construct3 file to just check if 'scroll to' behaviour works or not on just a simple sprite and it worked as it shold be. the camera moved as the sprite moved. but in the first case, i don't know what the hell is happening.
I am expecting someone to point out the mistake i am making and a solution for that.

You have 2 Hero objects in your game, both with the ScrollTo behaviour enabled. Disable the ScrollTo behaviour for the Hero instance above the play area and everything will work properly.

In Construct, if you enable ScrollTo on more than one object, the camera will be centered to the mid point of all ScrollTo objects.
